# I need to implement a multi-select having server end search using Javascript Preferably using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, multi-select

I need to implement a multi-select having server end search(auto complete sort of) using Javascript Preferably using bootstrap.

Please help me with the same.

Comment: What kind of help do you need ?

Comment: I was searching for a bootstrap component. Although I found that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several plugins in the below mentioned URL - 
http://coderbay.com/most-popular-jquery-multiselect-plugins/